# finding process bottlenecks rails/ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just got started with rails, and when I testing in development mode, I see in the logs that my Mailer action is taking 1175ms.  Is there anyway to find out what exactly is the slow step?

Also, there is a line that says (View:2, DB:1).  I assume the DB means number of database lookups, but what about the view?

Comment: Since this is happening in your mailer action, I suspect that the sending of the mail needs this much time. Which is why some sites use things like [DelayedJob](http://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job), [Resque](http://github.com/defunkt/resque) or similar

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find the performance bottlenecks in my Ruby application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480109/how-can-i-find-the-performance-bottlenecks-in-my-ruby-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try reading the [benchmarking and profiling guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/performance_testing.html) to learn how to find bottlenecks.

Also, the `View: 2, DB: 1` actually refers to the time spent in milliseconds in each part.

Answer (score 1):

If the mailer call is part of rendering a view you can use fiveruns-tuneup to dig into the calls and see which one is causing the delay. http://github.com/fiveruns/fiveruns_tuneup